# matlab equation of cylinder

Tags: matlab

I have written an equation of cylinder in matlab as follows

```
z=0;  
r=1/33;  
a=1/2+1/4-1/8-1/16;  
b=1/2+1/4-1/8-1/16;
if (x-a).^2+(y-b).^2<=r^2  
    z=1;  
end   
N=1-t(any number)
```

now I want to move it along x-axis with interval of time as above. I want to move it along x-axis
How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your equation `(x-a).^2+(y-b).^2<=r^2` means that the cylinder's center is at `[a, b]`. Moving it along the `x`-axis by an amount `da` means increasing `a` to `a+da`, so that the new center moves to `[a+da, b]`.

Just as a word of advice -- there is also the Matlab command `[x,y,z] = cylinder`. Type `help cylinder` for more info.

And for completeness and rigor -- your equation is *not* that of a cylinder, it is the equation of a plane (`z=0`) with a solid circular protrusion of height `1` and radius `1/33` centered at `[a,b]`. A "solid cylinder" like the one you've defined is best referred to as a "rod", whereas a mathematical "cylinder" is only the outer surface ("the collection of all points equidistant to a line segment"). Very often cylinders are defined through a set of parametric equations, so what are your reasons for this particular style of defining the rod?

Comment: actually I am using this as a function file in my code to place this rod in the mesh according to my choice of place. and now I want to move it along x axis in a time loop.

Comment: @user1131808 Well, now you know how :) Did you test my suggestion? Did it work?

Comment: I tried to do that but it is not working with my rest of code.